# 'No such file' error after reinstalling Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

At first I could not create a new Ruby project and I was getting a error about the bin path. I uninstalled ruby and reinstalled it.

Now I get this error whene executing `rails --version`:

```
mackbookpro:desktop 411techhelp$ rails --version
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:7:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:7
```

What is going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: accually this is when i do rails --version. I get this. At first I could not create a new project and I was getting a error about the bin path.But know i get this message up top after I uninstalled ruby and reinstalled it.now I can't run anything.

Comment: I have rewritten your question to address the actual sitution. The fact that you wanted to start a new projects is history now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks very much like uninstalling `ruby` also uninstalled `rubygems`, but you didn't [re-install the latter](https://rubygems.org/pages/download) (or your installation of `rubygems` is/was for a different `ruby` version).

Comment: okay I have ruby 1.8.7 installed and rubygems 1.5.2 , rails 3.2.12 and know i can create a new project, thanks.Im new to this so still learning!

Comment: Did you try explicitly reinstalling rubygems, using your current ruby installation? It might help if you could edit your question to show what steps you took to uninstall and reinstall ruby.